# javascript выдавал NaN по непонятным причинам, почему?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, nan

js отмечал время нажатия и отпускания клавиш, после чего считал время удержания каждой и выводил на экран значения.
Очень часто выводил на экран или весь массив, или отдельные значения **NaN**.

Методом проб и ошибок оказалось, что мешает клавиша **Tab**. То бишь, если за время сессии на странице была использована Tab - выводились NaN'ы.
За другими служебными клавишами такое не замечалось.

**JS:**

```
var time_down = [];
var time_up = [];
var time_press = [];
var count_up = 0;

document.getElementById('pass').addEventListener('onkeydown', setTime_down);
document.getElementById('pass').addEventListener('onkeyup', setTime_press);
document.getElementById('sub').addEventListener('onclick', writeResult_time);

function setTime_down() {
    time_down.push(new Date().getTime());
}

function setTime_press() {
    time_up.push(new Date().getTime());
    time_press.push(time_up[count_up] - time_down[count_up]);
    count_up++;
}

function writeResult_time() {
    time_press.push(time_up[time_up.length-1] - time_down[0]);
    document.getElementsByName("passTime_value")[0].value = time_press.join();
    alert(time_press);
}
```

Решилась проблема строкой:

```
<body onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==9) return false;">
```

Почему так происходило?
Может быть можно было решить проблему иначе, ведь многие привыкли использовать tab при переходе от поля логина к паролю?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то Tab нажимается когда курсор находится в поле? Тогда получается, что лиснер стартует, но так как Tab перемещает курсор в другое поле, то лиснер тут же прекращает свою работу и начинает для нового поля (если на него повешено) .... вроде все логично.

Comment: Лиснер стартует только в том поле, в которое мы переходим, если нажмем Tab. Да и в целом, даже если нужное поле вообще никак не задействовано, использование Tab, где бы то ни было, на странице - приводит к NaN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что при нажатии tab-a, событие `keyup` в "pass" происходило раньше, чем `keydown`, и `count` становился больше длины `time_down`.

Проверяйте длины массивов в `setTime_press`:

```
function setTime_press() {
  if (time_up.length < time_down.length) {
    time_up.push(new Date().getTime());
    time_press.push(time_up[count_up] - time_down[count_up]);
    count_up++;
  }
}
```

Comment: И как я не подумал об этом...
Спасибо большое.

Comment: А не подскажите еще, почему NaN вылазил не постоянно? Потому что, даже при использовании Tab, иногда бывало, что выводились нужные значения.

Comment: @ГудМан Хм, можно придумать какие-то сценарии это объясняющие. Например, Вы ушли с "pass" тоже tab-ом. После этого длины массивов уравнялись, и если Вы щелкните на "pass" мышкой, то все будет работать для последующих нажатий.

Comment: Я понял. Ну, главное, что с Tab'ом, таки, разрешилось и можно его не запрещать:)